# heic2any with file input

Tags: javascript, input

I can't get it to work for me with input file. I understand that this code uses fetch and should transform file to fetch but I have no idea.

heic2any:

```
fetch("https://alexcorvi.github.io/heic2any/demo/1.heic")
      .then((res) => res.blob())
      .then((blob) => heic2any({
        blob,
        toType:"image/jpeg",
        quality: 0.7
      }))
      .then((conversionResult) => {
    var reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(conversionResult);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
         base64data = reader.result;
         console.log(base64data);
          document.getElementById("target2").innerHTML = '<a download="image.webp" href="'+base64data+'">Download</a>';
          
    }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

input file:

```
<input id="image-file" type="file" onchange="SavePhoto(this)" >

<script><!-- comment -->
    function SavePhoto(f) 
{

    let photo = f.files[0];   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming you have the heic2any node module installed. If you don't you can install it with

> npm install heic2any

Blob is one of the object properties and should be 'blob: photo' instead of just blob. Fetch is not necessary if you already have the file from the file input.

```
function SavePhoto(f) {
    let photo = f.files[0];
    heic2any({
        blob: photo,
        toType: 'image/jpeg',
        quality: 0.7
    }).then(blob => {
       //use the converted blob to do whatever
       //maybe let newFile = new File(blob, fileName.jpg, { type: 'image/jpeg' }) or something
    }, error => {
        //handle errors
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to create a new File from the result you just need to add brackets around blob to give it a callable @@iterator property.

```
function SavePhoto(f) {
    let photo = f.files[0];
    heic2any({
        blob: photo,
        toType: 'image/jpeg',
        quality: 0.7,
    }).then(
        (blob) => {
            let newFile = new File([blob], fileName.jpg, { type: 'image/jpeg' });
            //whatever else you'd like to do with the new File
        },
        (error) => {
            //handle errors
        }
    );
}
```